# Showing $G$ is Abelian Using Uniqueness of Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group with an element $g$ such that for any group $H$ and $h\in H$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\theta:G\rightarrow H$ such that $\theta(g)=h$. Show that $G$ is abelian.

So far, I've only been able to show that $g\in Z(G)$ by mapping to the group $G\times G$ via the homomorphisms $\phi(x)=(g^{-1}xg,x)$ and $\psi(x)=(x,g^{-1}xg)$. Since $\phi(g)=\psi(g)=(g,g)$, it follows by hypothesis that $\phi\equiv\psi$, and so $\phi(a)=(g^{-1}ag,a)=\psi(a)=(a,g^{-1}ag)$, whence $g^{-1}ag=a$ and so $ag=ga$. But I can't seem to figure out how to show all elements of $G$ are in the center. I have a feeling I'll feel foolish once I see it.

Comment: Hint: Show $g$ has infinite order (easy) and that every element of $G$ is a power of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I think I have it, then:

The maps $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ and $\psi:G\rightarrow G$ defined by $\phi(x)=g^{-1}xg$ and $\psi(x)=x$ are homomorphisms. Since $\phi(g)=\psi(g)=g$, $\phi\equiv\psi$, and so for any $a\in G$, $g^{-1}ag=a$, and hence $ag=ga$. Thus, $g\in Z(G)$.

Let $\phi:G\rightarrow G/Z(G)$ be the natural projection and let $\psi:G\rightarrow G/Z(G)$ be the trivial homomorphism. Then $\phi(g)=\psi(g)=Z(G)$, so that by hypothesis $\phi\equiv\psi$. But then for any $x\in G$, $\phi(x)=xZ(G)=\psi(x)=Z(G)$, so that $x\in Z(G)$. Hence, $G=Z(G)$, and so we are done.